# How to handle ViewExpiredException by showing JavaScript alert?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, myfaces, viewexpiredexception

I've read the question [Handle ViewExireException/ajax and display a Primefaces dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340357/handle-viewexireexception-ajax-and-display-a-primefaces-dialog) and the answer from BalusC. I'd want to handle the `ViewExpiredException` by showing the alert with information to refresh the page. I've taken the suggestion from BalusC to user `RequestContext`to put JavaScript to execute, and I've removed the JSF redirection because I'm not using it:

```
@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
        Throwable t = context.getException();
        if (t instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
            ViewExpiredException vee = (ViewExpiredException) t;
            try {
                log.info("Catched ViewExpiredException for view {}", vee.getViewId());
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("handleViewExpired("+vee.getViewId()+")");
                return;
            } finally {
                i.remove();
            }
        } 
    }
    // At this point, the queue will not contain any ViewExpiredEvents.
    // Therefore, let the parent handle them.
    getWrapped().handle();

}
```

The problem is, I got `NullPointerException` when executing the handle method from `wrapped` handler. I've added the return clause, and after adding it, the effect was the same:

> [30.01.13 15:45:59:140 CET] 0000002e ErrorPageWrit E   An exception
>   occurred
>                                    javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   my.project.web.handler.ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler.handle(ViewExpiredExceptionExceptionHandler.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)

So, the parent handle method is executed, thought there should be the return from method (The info string is logged).

I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.4** and **MyFaces 2.0.7**, everything on **WebSphere 7**.

I don't understand what is happening here. Is it possible to achieve what I want, and if so, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For MyFaces guys it'd be helpful if you tell MyFaces version (and in the meanwhile, try latest version and report back if it still contains the bug).

Comment: So you say it's a bug, and a code in such form should generally be working, without those return in processing?

Comment: For latest version of MyFaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230905/classnotfoundexception-classutils-when-trying-to-use-myfaces-2-1-10-with-ibm-we, so it's impossible to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way was to handle that exception on client side. It's very simple few-liner and it's completly transparent:

```
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse;
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse = function(data, status, xhr) {
  var errorName = $(data.documentElement).find("error-name").text();
  if (errorName == 'javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException') {
    alert('View has expired, redirection will follow');
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};
```

No 2 new classes on server, no `faces-config.xml` changes, this is what I love in programming.

Comment: Im sorry but is this in javascript in the xhtml? Or where do I put it? I just tried in the javascript above the form that's giving me ViewExpiredException and it doesn't work. I'm with Websphere and richfaces.